# Async Javascript Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method 'test'

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to create my first javascript file that loads asynchronously, but am having trouble with calling functions from the object afterwards.  Below is my example javascript file exampletest.js...

```
(function(){
    var example = {
        test : function () {
            alert("test function called");
        }
    };
    window.example = example;
})();
```

I then try to call this file using the following code.

```
    (function(doc, example) {
            window.example = example;

            var script = doc.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.async = true;
            script.src = "http://www.example.com/exampletest.js";

            var scriptTag = doc.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            scriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(script, scriptTag);
    })(document, window.example || []);

    example.test();
```

When I run this script I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'test'"

If I call the method after the page has loaded, say on a link click, the test method is properly called and I get my alert box.

I've been searching around trying to understand this better but have so far been out of luck.  I'm trying to better understand how I could call a function without getting the has no method 'test'.  Is there a way to push the function call after the javascript has loaded without junking up the call itself so it stays example.test();?

Comment: I can't reproduce this error: http://jsfiddle.net/WVvV7/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just check whether the function exist before you call it.

Try this :

```
if (typeof example.test == function){
    example.test();
}
```

Note: As the JavaScript is loaded asynchronously, `window.onload` won't work.

**Update**

The whole purpose of having `async` is to load the page without waiting for the scripts to load. You cannot have both.

This won't work

```
<script src="exampletest.js"  async ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    example.test();
</script>
```

but this will work, as the execution waits for the file to load

```
<script src="exampletest.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    example.test();
</script>
```

Comment: is there a way around this?  I'd like to have it so I can call example.test(); without having it to be specifically in a window.onload.  Long term I'd like to give users a the script so they can cut and paste it into their site and then call the methods with no problem.

Comment: Is there a way around this by checking for this type of thing in my script file?  I'm trying to have it so the client that installs my js will only need to call example.test() or any other method calls I have.  I've seen similar things from other companies that have copy/paste script installs (like Google Analytics), but I haven't been able to figure out how they handle this problem.

Comment: The other alternative is to make your script load syncronously.

Comment: @user2023918 Google Analytics doesn't have any functions called inside the HTML page. All calls happen within the loaded script. Also, they don't do `async`.